# Scrape data from JavaScript-rendered website

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to scrap [Lulu webstore](http://www.luluwebstore.com). I have the following problems with it.

- The website content is loaded dynamically.
- The website when tried to access, redirects to choose country page.
- After choosing country, it pops up select delivery location and then redirects to home page.
- When you try to hit end page programmatically, you get an empty response because the content is loaded dynamically.

I have a list of end URLs from which I have to scrape data. For example, consider [mobile accessories](http://www.luluwebstore.com/categories/lulu-mobiles--tablets-mobiles-mobile-accessories/cid-CU00214732.aspx). Now I want to

- Get the HTML source of that page directly, which is loaded dynamically bypassing choose country, select location popups, so that I can use my Scrapy Xpath selectors to extract data.
- If you suggest me to use Selenium, PhantomJS, Ghost or something else to deal with dynamic content, please understand that I want the end HTML source as in a web browser after processing all dynamic content which will be sent to Scrapy.
- Also, I tried using proxies to skip choose country popup but still it loads it and select delivery location.
- I've tried using Splash, but it returns me the source of choose country page.

Comment: Well dinamic content mean AJAX call. Just get the structure of the request, then call it in a loop with the id's of the products. Usually you would only need the `requests` module for that, in combination with `BeautifulSoup`. Same goes with location i guess.

Comment: @Cal Eliacheff Thanks for the comment but the problem with your way is that even if i make requests with cookies and user-agents as same as a web browser still i get the same response. I need something in between response from server and script which will process those dynamic content and gives the end result so that i can feed that to scrapy.

Comment: You should look better at the calls. The location is stored inside the cookie you get from the `SelectLocation.aspx`. For example: `http://www.luluwebstore.com/SelectLocation.aspx?Location=13241&DeliveryMode=H&ReturnUrl=http://www.luluwebstore.com` allow you to bypass the country selection. It's looks like there is only GET requests, which are generally simpler to use. IMHO you don't wan't to use scrapy for this kind of sites.

Comment: @Cal Eliacheff I'm really sorry I didn't understand your comment. But i can't find any `SelectLocation.aspx` or similar script/cookie to set location. Also, I'm new to dynamic content crawling. Can you explain it more clearer? Also i've referred the cookies from the web browser's request headers and have also included in headers.

Comment: Well, inside a requests.Session, call to the above url to go to the main page, then you can now make call to the products. Tip: just use the network tab of the dev tools to see what's happen (you can filter just the html and xhr events), then just copy the prosess using `requests`.

Comment: @Cal Eliacheff I've successfully bypassed those country and delivery address pop ups but now another problem came the content of the page is loading dynamically. Is there any way to get the final html source of the web page? The flow of the webpage is like this it does post to `carthandler .ashx` and loads cart and then a get is sent to  `productshowcasehandler.ashx` which seems to load the data and then `getandset` is called I don't have any idea what it is doing. After that `productshowcasehandler.ashx` is called in order to load the page in infinite crawl.

Comment: I don't know which script is calling `productshowcasehandler.ashx` from where how can i find out? I didn't see any possible way of tracing it out in chrome's developer tools.

Comment: In chrome dev tool go to network tab → load a page →  find lines with something.aspx or .ashx (GET calls or AJAX requests). Click on them you will get all the requests details + response in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I found answer. I used EditThisCookie plugin to view the cookies that are loaded by the Web Page. I found that it stores 3 cookies `CurrencyCode,ServerId,Site_Config` in my local storage. I used the above mentioned plugin to copy the cookies in JSON format. I referred [this manual](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) for setting cookies in the requests.

Now I'm able to skip those location,delivery address popups. After that I found that the dynamic pages are loaded via `<script type=text/javascript>` and found that part of page url is stored in a variable. I extracted the value using `split()`. Here is the script part to get the dynamic page url.

```
from lxml import html
page_source=requests.get(url,cookies=jar)
tree=html.fromstring(page_source.content)    
dynamic_pg_link=tree.xpath('//div[@class="col3_T02"]/div/script/text()')[0] #entire javascript to load product pages
dynamic_pg_link=dynamic_pg_link.split("=")[1].split(";")[0].strip()#obtains the dynamic page url.
page_link="http://www.luluwebstore.com/Handler/ProductShowcaseHandler.ashx?ProductShowcaseInput="+dynamic_pg_link
```

Now I'm able to extract data from these LInks.

Thanks to @Cal Eliacheff for the previous guidance.